# Azure Mobile App Quick Start "could not install mobileappsmanagement site extension"

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

When I create a Mobile App and try to access the quick start blade I get the error: "could not install mobileappsmanagement site extension". 
I am a student and all of my fellow students have the same problem. 
Subscription is F1 Free tier. Have tried resetting browser cache etc. 
The strange thing is that I had created a Mobile App a couple weeks ago and it was working fine even at the same time I was having this problem with my second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a problem in the portal and corrected it.  Please clear your cache and try again.

Thank you for the problem report.